# Ajax POST request is empty

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

I tried to upload files with Ajax. But POST request is empty.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', files[0].name);
alert(files[0].name);
$("#form_upload").submit();
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/dropupload/",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: fd,
    success: function(data) {
        waitforprocess();
    },
    complete: function(data){
        alert(formdata.size)
    },
    error: function(){
        allert("error")
    }
});
```

in views 
POST is emty

```
def post(request):
    q = request.POST.get("file")
```

q = None

Why POST is empty?

Comment: Just a quick note that `FormData()` is not supported by all/older browsers - for example, IE requires v10+, which in turn requires at least Windows 7.

Comment: is your form multipart add enctype='multipart/form-data' if not.

Answer (score 1):

Try serializing the form data instead of creating a new FormData object. Like:

```
var $form = $("#form_upload").find('form');
var fd = $form.serialize();
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var fd = new FormData($("#form")[0]);
```

Also, make sure, your form declaration is correct:

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">                        
    <input type="file" name="file" />
</form>
```